# Save values from the first launch and I want to keep using that value. How can I do this?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing an app that gets identification number and age at the first launch.
I also want to use these values later on. Where should I save these values in?

Is it automatically saved?

My language is Swift.

Comment: Stash it in a file? Hard to answer without much more details...

Comment: Your needs seems rather simple so NSUserDefaults is probably  good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628225/how-do-you-save-local-storage-data-in-a-swift-application

Comment: #Stefan Oh this is the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can save them in `NSUserDefaults`,

```
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[def setObject:@"value:@"key"];
[def synchronize];
```

Comment: what does synchronize do?

Comment: It will write user defaults on disk immediately... but you can ignore some time its slow