# macOS swift - save data to local storage - best practices

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm a newbie in macOS development. I have an application where I need to save a string (for example a token) to some local storage, and after closing and opening app I want to retrieve this string back.

Is it somehow possible that only my app would be able to retrieve this string?

Is it better to write it to the `txt` file or there are some other possibilities?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the security of the data.

- If security matters save the string in the keychain.
- If security does not matter save the string in `UserDefaults`