# How to add specific information from view to alert message after pressing a button?

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Main screen]

I'm trying to work on a code that when the user touches the "ADD TO CART" button, the information currently displayed will be shown on an alert message when the user touches the "VIEW ORDERS" button. I've tried the answer from this question ([How to save local data in a Swift app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628225/how-do-you-save-local-storage-data-in-a-swift-application)), but I've found that it doesn't work for me and I've been stuck ever since.

["VIEW ORDERS" button's alert screen (left side). Alert screen after adding another item to cart (right side)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7bL3.png)

edit: Don't have xcode on this computer so I just made screen in paint.

Comment: which Swift version you use ?

Comment: I use version 7.1, sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: let alert = UIAlertView(title: "YOUR TITLE", message: "YOUR MESSAGE", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8

Comment: Dont warry about this its show you alert

Comment: @thepersonwho check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Following code for alert view Controller :

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    let margin:CGFloat = 8.0
    let rect = CGRectMake(margin, margin, alertController.view.bounds.size.width - margin * 4.0, 100.0)
    let customView = UITextView(frame: rect)
    customView.text = "OREDERTEXT\nOREDERTEXT"
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    customView.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 15)

    alertController.view.addSubview(customView)

    let somethingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("something")

        print(customView.text)

    })

    alertController.addAction(somethingAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:{})
```

I hope this will helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code its working completely fine.**

**YOUR FIRST ALERT**

```
let message = "BRAND : BRNAD \n MODEL : MODEL \n PRICE : 25$"
let alertController = UIAlertController(
        title: "", // This gets overridden below.
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: .Alert
 )
 let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) { _ -> Void in
 }
 alertController.addAction(okAction)
 self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

**YOUR SECOND ALERT..**

```
let message = "BRAND : BRNAD \n MODEL : MODEL \n PRICE : 25$ \n\n\n BRAND : BRAND \n MODEL : MODEL \n PRICE : 120$ \n"
let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "", // This gets overridden below.
            message: message,
            preferredStyle: .Alert
)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) { _ -> Void in
}
alertController.addAction(okAction)
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]