# How to skip the login scene and start straight from the next if you are already authorized?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, storyboard, segue

What is the best place to check if the user is already logged-in and how to realize the transition to the first app scene skipping the login viewController?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you save local storage data in a swift application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628225/how-do-you-save-local-storage-data-in-a-swift-application)

Comment: It differs from storing some user settings locally (NSUserDefaults and CoreData) because I need to make userActive check before deciding which scene will be initial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do this in my AppDelegate. In my main storyboard, my initial view controller assumes that my user is logged in. Thus, in my AppDelegate I do the following to decide whether I need to show the login screen:

```
// Show login view if not currently logged in
if (!currentUser){

    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: MainStoryboardId, bundle: Bundle.main)
    let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: loginViewControllerId)

    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    window.rootViewController = vc
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

PS, just converted code from Objective-C... it's untested.

Comment: Glad you like it. If you use it, feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 11):

You could try something like that:

- In your FirstViewController you check if the user is logged in. If so, you push the MainViewController, if not you push the LoginViewController and after login you push the MainViewController.

You can build a interface for FirstViewController cloning the Splash Interface, so the user won't note you have another viewcontroller before Login.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Wow, Allan! Thank you so much for you clear visual answer. One my friend told me that I should try this Splash stuff and I didn't understand what's he talking about.

Comment: what if the user log out