# iOS - Is saving to UserDefaults synchronous?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Are operations on UserDefaults synchronous? For example does the second save wait for the first save to finish?

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(myValue1, forKey: "myValue1")
UserDefaults.standard.set(myValue2, forKey: "myValue2")
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808072/when-and-why-should-you-use-nsuserdefaultss-synchronize-method for related details that may help clarify what's going on.

Comment: Yes it is `synchronous`. Also there is no function for saving with completion block.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults):

> At runtime, you use UserDefaults objects to read the defaults that your app uses from a user’s defaults database. UserDefaults caches the information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults database each time you need a default value. **When you set a default value, it’s changed synchronously within your process, and asynchronously to persistent storage and other processes.**

Comment: so its not; no guarantee value was persistend, ughh