# Swift 2 migration saveContext() in appDelegate

Tags: swift, swift2

I have just downloaded the new Xcode 7.0 beta and did a migration from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2. The migration apparently did not change the whole code, in fact a method saveContext() which was fine until throws 2 errors for the line:

```
if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save() {
```

> Binary operator '&&' cannot be applied to two Bool operands

and

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

The method looks like this:

```
// MARK: - Core Data Saving support
func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save() {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to get it working?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The first of the two errors you provided is misleading, but the second is spot on. The problem is in `!moc.save()` which as of Swift 2, no longer returns Bool and is instead annotated `throws`. This means that you you have to `try` this method and `catch` any exceptions that it may emit, instead of just checking wether its return value is true or false.

To reflect this, a new project created in Xcode 7 using Core Data will produce the following boilerplate code which can replace the code you're using.

```
func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's the right answer, In addition, You need to add an `!` after managedObjectContext so the line looks like: `if managedObjectContext!.hasChanges {` and `try managedObjectContext!.save()`

Comment: @kalafun No, in Xcode 7 the managedObjectContext is not optional. Will post update on my answer

Comment: That is strange I am using xcode 7 beta and it threw an error because of the missing exclamation mark. Waiting for your update..

Comment: @kalafun The problem is that you're still using the `lazy var managedObjectContext` that was generated in a lower version of Xcode. In Xcode 7, this property is generated as non-optional.

Answer (score 9):

The answer by 0x7fffffff is correct, but to improve upon Apple's boilerplate code, you can catch the specific error in the catch block using `catch let error as NSError` like so:

```
func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {

            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            // Handle Error
        }
    }
}
```

The best practice is to use the var `error` witch will still be available if you just use it this way :

```
func saveContext () {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                // Handle Error
            }
        }
    }
```

In the same way, if you are sure that `managedObjectContext.save()` will not `throw` an `exception`, the code is slimmed down to:

```
func saveContext () {
     if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        try! managedObjectContext.save()
     }
}
```

And to extrapolate on why `managedObjectContext` is not optional in the Swift 2 code, it is because the `NSManagedObject(concurrencyType:)` is an initializer that does not fail. In Xcode 6, the boilerplate code returned an optional context if the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is nil, but you can handle this easily by checking.

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return moc
}()
```