# Swift 2.0 Migration errors

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I've watched the WWDC sessions, reading the new programmers book on Swift, and reading all the related questions on Stack Overflow I could find. I fixed most errors in my app after migrating from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0.

However there's still a few that I've not managed to solve.

**Downcasting AnyObject**

Error:

> Cannot downcast from '[AnyObject]' to a more optional type '[NSManagedObject]'

Code:

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: formulaEntity)
    
    var error: NSError?
    
    do {
        let fetchedResults = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]?
        
        if let results = fetchedResults {
            stocks = results
        } else {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("ERROR: \(error)")
    }
```

The error shown is happening in the `let fetchedResults = try...` line

Another strange error I'm having is in my AppDelegate:

Error:

> 'NSMutableDictionary' is not convertible to '[NSObject : AnyObject]'

Code:

```
    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Stocks.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch var error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict as [NSObject : AnyObject])
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    return coordinator
}()
```

I have not ever touched the code above. So I have no idea why this wasn't migrated properly, by Apple's Migration tool.

Another error in my AppDelegate:

> Binary operator '&&' cannot be applied to two Bool operands
>
> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled.

Code:

```
func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save() {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

Again I havn't touched this part of AppDelegate, and not sure what exactly is wrong with the code above.

Comment: For #1, `try` unwraps the optional for you on success so just remove the question mark.

Comment: For #2, `save()` might throw an error so it needs to execute with `try`, instead of being evaluated as a bool.

Comment: @AaronBrager Watched that already :), helped me fix the vast majority of my errors, had over 100 after Migration... But these wasn't mentioned in that video.

Comment: Your problem about `if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save()` is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729011/swift-2-migration-savecontext-in-appdelegate. – Your first problem is more or less the same because `managedContext.executeFetchRequest()` does not return an optional anymore.

Comment: @AaronBrager Will try your suggestions right away thanks! Also I just found the solution for my UIButton. I'll edit that out first.

Comment: AaronBrager Thank you so much! 1 and 4 was the solution to my problems in 1 line of comments!. Problem 2 however, I could not find "save()" anywhere. Where am I supposed to "try" that? Also you can go ahead and provide an answer. In case anyone else runs into the same issues.

MartinR Thanks for the link to that, that solved my second error :D Sorry I wasn't able to find that before.

Comment: See Martin's link for sample code to resolve.

Comment: @AaronBrager That's for error 3. I fixed that from Martin's link, Any idea how to fix the one with the dictionary?

Comment: The error means that a Swift-only object can't be added to an NSDictionary. I think it's because `error` is a struct conforming to `ErrorType`. Try adding `error1` instead.

Comment: @AaronBrager That fixed it :) Thank you once again. Do you want to provide an answer? Despite the many quick downvotes my question is getting, I havn't been able to find any SO answers for 2 of the errors I ran into.

Comment: @MarkL Sure, I'll write something up. Not sure why you're getting the downvotes. Seems like a well-written question, and only the Core Data issue was answered elsewhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cannot downcast from '[AnyObject]' to a more optional type '[NSManagedObject]'

In Swift 1.2, `executeFetchRequest(:_)` returned `[AnyObject]?`. In Swift 2, it returns `[AnyObject]` because the new `try`… syntax returns a non-optional.

(In the case that the method would return `nil`, the method would not return at all, and control would move to the `catch` block.)

---

> 'NSMutableDictionary' is not convertible to '[NSObject : AnyObject]'

This means you're trying to insert something into an `NSMutableDictionary` that can't be converted to an Objective-C object. In your case, I think it's because `error` is a struct conforming to `ErrorType`, rather than an `NSError` object. Try adding `error1` instead.

---

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled.

`save()` might throw an error so it needs to be executed with `try`, instead of being evaluated as a `bool`. As Martin R. points out in the comments, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30729011/1445366) provides a complete solution so I won't rehash it here.

Answer (score 9):

It seems there is a severe Swift 2 migration problem for CoreData on AppDelegate. I was able to fix the problem by completely replacing the AppDelegate CoreData Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0.

What you need to do is delete the following

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext ()
```

And pasting the Swift 2.0 code:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
         }
     }
 }
}
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: If it doesn't work, try to create a new Xcode project with CoreData. Then replace the CoreData code in your app delegate with the one in the new project. Let me know if this solves it. Thanks

Comment: my fault - solution is fine! Just needed to change SingleViewCoreData.sqlite to my sqlite file name

Comment: Great.. Happy it gave you the solution.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error too. The problem is, the error appears only when I uncomment a totally unrelated `if let` block in a different file. Also, my project is Swift 2 from the start...